# Set esp32 access point web server using Micropython

Tags: python, firmware, microcontroller

I am trying to run a mini web server on my ESP32 feather huzzah32, but I hit an error every time I try to open the console. I tried several times, updated everything, erased the flash also few time to start over and the same.

The line 37 seems to have a problem I cannot figure out.
When I am done with compiling and upload the code, I see this error:

> (IOError @[0047:0013:0000:0048:0000:0000:0000:0000]
>   oops, something wrong while linkin:
>   (IOError at line 37 of main raised at line 97 of wireless.wifi.link

Here is my code.

```
import streams
import socket


from wireless import wifi


from espressif.esp32net import esp32wifi as wifi_driver

streams.serial()

wifi_driver.auto_init()

    wifi.link("my-ssid",wifi.WIFI_WPA2,"my-password")
except Exception as e:
    print("ooops, something wrong while linking :(", e)
    while True:
        sleep(1000)


print("Linked!")

info = wifi.link_info()
print("My IP is:",info[0])

sock = socket.socket()
sock.bind(80)
sock.listen()


while True:
    try:


        client = streams.SocketStream(clientsock)


        line = client.readline()
        while line!="\n" and line!="\r\n":
            line = client.readline()
        print("HTTP request received!")


        print("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r",stream=client)
        print("Content-Type: text/html\r",stream=client)
        print("Connection: close\r\n\r",stream=client)

        print("<html><body>Hello Zerynth!",random(0,100),"</body></html>",stream=client)

        client.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print("ooops, something wrong:",e)
```

I am using Zerynth.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. It was a bit silly but often errors are indeed silly. Istead of using routers SSID, I tried with the name of the WIFI network and it worked just fine. There is the code, line 37.

```
wifi.link("NAME_OF_THE_NETWORK",wifi.WIFI_WPA2,"NETWORK_PASSWORD")
```